# How to enter Erlang Mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do I enter erlang mode in `emacs` to get syntax highlighting? Whenever I open an erlang file nothing special happens. Do I need to change something in my `.emacs` file, or do I need to add a module to emacs, or something else?

Answer (score 7):

Emacs doesn't come with an Erlang mode, so you need to add one. Erlang itself appears to ship with an Emacs mode that you can use; there are instructions on [installing it](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html) and [using it](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.el.html) on their website, but it comes down to just adding their folders to your load path and exec path, setting a variable, and requiring the module:

```
(setq load-path (cons  "/usr/local/otp/lib/tools-<ToolsVer>/emacs" load-path))
(setq erlang-root-dir "/usr/local/otp")
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/otp/bin" exec-path))
(require 'erlang-start)
```

The paths might be different depending on where you installed Erlang

Comment: thanks. how do i find where otp is installed? is there an erl command for it?

Answer (score 1):

As of 22 March 2013, the Erlang mode is installable through the [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) package archive.  If you haven't done so already, activate MELPA by putting the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
```

Then hit `M-x list-packages` and install the `erlang` package.